# Is it possible to create a game scene that saves an animation file as an asset in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to know that if it's possible to have a game scene in your game that allows any player to animate a character?

Let's ignore the cognitive load a player will face while animating a character and assume that, somehow, we manage to abstractly present it in a game scene. Can we make it happen that after player's making of certain animation, unity stores that in a .anim file and in the next game scene the player can play a character having that specific animation?

I think calling it real time in-game animation creation would describe it.

Comment: Very broad answer, yes, its possible. Animations are just data. Will it be easy? No. Will Unity automatically import it for you? No.

Comment: look into UnityRecorder addon, I haven't used it but I think it lets you record animations without writing code